# Как добавить SameSite атрибут к cookie файлам

Tags: google-chrome

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я прочитал в интернете про то, что cookie файлам нужно добавлять SameSite атрибут, чтобы избавиться от таких сообщений в консоли. Также я узнал, что этот атрибут может указывать на то, чтобы не кешировать мои файлы на других сайтах, где это не нужно(а мне это нигде не нужно). Но я не понимаю, куда это прописывать.
Примечание: я сам нигде не создаю и не управляю файлами `cookie`

1) Первое сообщение в консоли - это я ссылаюсь фото с ресурса picsum.photos, таким образом: `<img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="">`
2) Я точно не пойму откуда это, но я использую Google Fonts, на который ссылаюсь по ссылке в css файле `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');`, а также я использую плагин LiveReload для перезагрузки страницы, возможно из-за него
Я хочу убрать эти предупреждения ко всем ссылкам, на сторонние сайты, для плагина это необязательно, но я не хочу, чтобы это видел пользователь в своей консоли.
P.S.: Вариант, чтобы отключить эти сообщение из `chrome://flags/` по названию `Cookie Deprecation messages` не подходит, так как это уберёт сообщения только в том браузере, где я снял этот флаг.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле .htaccess:

```
Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ "$1; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=lax"
```

Также с версии 7.3 php поддерживает добавление этого заголовка в php.ini:

```
session.cookie_samesite=Lax
```

Это должно решить проблему.

Comment: А через `javascript` можно добавить, не знаете?

Comment: Вряд ли , только конфиги Apache или php , но это точно работает, попробуйте написать в поддержку вашего хостинга если нет доступа к этим файлам , вдруг

Comment: Если это не ваши куки, то тем более

Answer (score 0):

Можно через javascript, если cookie устанавливаются через javascript.
Добавить параметр sameSite=Lax так же, как параметры path, expire или domain.

Если пользуетесь jquery.cookie, надо поправить jquery.cookie.js  там, где формируются options (67-74 строка): *options.sameSite  ? '; sameSite=' + options.sameSite : '',*.
И не забыть при формировании или удалении cookie добавить параметр {'sameSite':'Lax'}.